# firebase database security rules: limiting reads and writes for only participants?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have my datastore currently set up like this:

```
"event": {
  "$eventID": {
       "participants": {
           "$uid1": true
           "$uid2" : true
           ...
        }
      ...Other event details objects...
    }
 },

"eventParticipants": {
       $uid: {
          $eventId1,
          $eventI2,
          ...
        }
       ...more users
 }
```

I would like to have it such that only users who are in the participant list of a event can read or write to that cascade but I'm having some trouble getting it to work properly. In the firebase console, I've tested this rule set out and it works in the test console, but the data doesn't actually show up unless I have a global read:"auth !=null"

Here's the rules I've tried:

```
 "event": {
    ".write": "auth != null", 

    "$eventID": {
         ".read": "root.child('eventParticipants').child(auth.uid).child($eventId).val() == true",
            "participants": {

            "$uid": {

               },
            },
        },
},

"eventParticipants": {
      ".write": "auth != null", 
        "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid ", 
      },
},
```

Here's the rules I've attempted with:

```
 "event": {
    ".write": "auth != null", 
    //".read": "auth != null", 


    "$eventID": {
         ".read": "root.child('eventParticipants').child(auth.uid).child($eventId).val() == true",
                 //".read": "root.child('eventParticipants/'+$uid+'/').val() === auth.uid",
                //   ".read": "data.parent().val() === auth.uid",
                //".validate": "$uid.exists()"

            "participants": {
             // ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()", 
             //".read": "data.child() == auth.uid",  

            "$uid": {
                //".read": "root.child('eventParticipants/'+$uid+'/').val() === auth.uid",
                //   ".read": "data.parent().val() === auth.uid",
                //".validate": "$uid.exists()"
               },
            },
        },
},

"eventParticipants": {
      ".write": "auth != null", 
      //".read": "auth != null", 
        "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid ", 
      },
},
```

Been scratching my head for days with this issue. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Too Late to Answer but Sharing this if Someone Else Came Across this same Problem.

Child Rules are Only Consistent if Parents Rules are Defined.

If Parents Ruled are not defined than by default read and write are false.

In your case you are defining write rules but not rules for .read

that's why you can ould not read in child Node.